# How to partition with GParted?

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, gparted

I have just copied my Ubuntu 64bit ISO into my USB Flash Drive and booted from there. It's my first time using a Linux distro, right now I'm using Windows 8 and writing this from the *Try Ubuntu* option. I'm just trying to install Ubuntu along with Windows 8, to keep both and select which one I want to start when I turn on my machine. I know there are similar questions, but no one helped me.

I execute the GParted program to make a partition of the hard disk. This is what I have.

[image]

Can you see the red icon at the */dev/sda2* partition? That's the Windows 8 system, and the *sda1* is the Windows 8 booter (as far as I know). I do right-click on the *sda2* partition and try to reduce the size to something like 700mb to let 300mb to my new Ubuntu system. But it's locked. It doesn't let me to resize or touch anything. It let me when resizing the *sda1* partition but not the one with the red icon.

This is what I'm getting while doing Right-click > Information on */dev/sda2*.

[image]

I'm very very new in this Linux-based world, so, how can I make a new partition to install this beautiful operating system?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved according to [Archlinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157882)

you have to run `chkdsk /f`in cmd inside Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the partition in question and choose "information", the window that appears should explain the reason behind the warning symbol, which I imagine will tell you why you cannot resize it.

**Edit:**

Looks like your Windows file system is a little inconsistent. Boot back into Windows, and check the drive for errors (find the drive in (My) Computer, right-click, check for errors is usually in the tools tab or similar.) If it is your system partition you may have to schedule the disk check to be done at the next reboot.

Alternatively if you press F8 on Windows start-up to get into the boot/recovery options, you can go into the repair/recovery mode and check the disk from there - you may need to do it manually from the command line with chkdsk (sorry I can't be more helpful here - I haven't encountered Windows 8 yet!)

Once Windows has cleaned up the filesystem, hopefully gparted will be prepared to resize it for you :)

Comment: You are right. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Answer updated accordingly :)

Comment: I solved this with the @microarm15 answer, but +1 for your dedication and help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the red-mark on the ntfs partition,

- click on the gparted option in the menu bar and select Refresh Devices.

  OR
- Boot into windows and make a restart (not shutdown).

  OR
- Check for bad blocks in that partition using `chkdsk` in windows or [`ntfsfix`](http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/howto-fix-an-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu/) utility in Ubuntu.

Comment: The third option works, as @microarm15 said. +1 Thanks!